# How can I read custom return data from a transaction?

Tags: anchor, rpc

I have a program (using Anchor), and a I wish to return a value from an RPC call. I understand that this was not possible a few months ago but now is, though I'm having trouble finding any docs/examples.

Edit: example here: https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/tests/cpi-returns/tests/cpi-return.ts#L45-L68

Answer (score 4, accepted):

implementing this in anchor is trivial(you dont need to use set_return_data or get_return_data sys calls) , instead of returning result<()>, replace the unit "()"
with the type of value you wish to return, this value can be accessed by programs cpi'ing or from the client side, check out this cpi return repo on anchor tests to get a better understanding, anchor also exposes a view function view the return value ,
Reference : https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/tree/master/tests/cpi-returns

Comment: Ok, I think this specifically is what I need, thanks!
https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/tests/cpi-returns/tests/cpi-return.ts#L45-L68

Comment: Hi @Nabeel Naveed, I tried the code but the result of getTransaction fn is null. Do you know why is that?